# Angular Translate: $translate undefined in controller

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection, angular-translate

I am using ng-show with a custom function. This function calls '$translate.use'-method inside the controller.

Funny enough, this works for the main-page but not for all other controllers although all of them use the same peace of code.

The console tells me that $translate is undefined.

Here's my peace of code for the index-page:

```
app.controller('LangCtrl', function ($scope, $translate) {

    $scope.isenglish = function () {
        if ($translate.use() == 'en_US') {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }........
```

and for another controller:

```
app.controller('selectFormController', ['$scope', '$http', 'storage', '$rootScope', function ($scope, $http, storage, $rootScope, $translate) {
```

........

```
  $scope.isenglish = function () {
        if ($translate.use() == 'en_US') {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

I am really puzzled - is anybody able to help me out?

Thanks a lot!!!
Steffen

Comment: I guess you have a typo.. app.controller('selectFormController', ['$scope', '$http', 'storage', '$rootScope', function ($scope, $http, storage, $rootScope, $translate) { should be app.controller('selectFormController', ['$scope', '$http', 'storage', '$rootScope',' $translate', function ($scope, $http, storage, $rootScope, $translate) {

Answer (score 3):

Its working in `LangCtrl` controller because you directly injecting `$translate` dependency. But in your `selectFormController` controller you are using inline array annotation you need to add dependency in array as `string`(dependency name) first and then you could use it inside the controller `function`

In short you missed to add `$translate` dependency in your `selectFormController` controller.

**Code**

```
app.controller('selectFormController', ['$scope', '$http', 'storage', '$rootScope', '$translate', 
function ($scope, $http, storage, $rootScope, $translate) {
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you're not really injecting `$translate`, check this out:

```
app.controller('selectFormController', ['$scope', '$http', 'storage', '$rootScope', '$translate', function ($scope, $http, storage, $rootScope, $translate)
```

Mind the `$translate` after `$rootScope`

Comment: embarassing... ;-) THANK YOU